# How to save checkpoints in survival mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-heroes

The game I'm referring to is **Call of Duty: Heroes**, the Android version.

I have seen following text written in survival mode screen

> Survival mode resumes at the furthest checkpoint you have reached with
>   more than 75% base health. All rewards up to that point will be given
>   to you EACH time you resume Survival Mode.

But I have crossed many waves but, It always resumes from wave 1,

How can we save checkpoint to resume from the same checkpoints?

Comment: What is the farthest wave you have gotten to? Have you gotten past wave six with greater than 75% base health?

Comment: Yes, I was more than 75 in 5th and then 6th and totally damaged in 7th